# MySQL query with 2 joins, large keylen leads to 'Copying to tmp table on disk' process hanging forever

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, join, sql-order-by

I'm sure I must be doing something stupid, but as is often the case I can't figure out what it is.

I'm trying to run this query:

```
SELECT `f`.`FrenchWord`, `f`.`Pronunciation`, `e`.`EnglishWord`
FROM (`FrenchWords` f)
INNER JOIN `FrenchEnglishMappings` m ON `m`.`FrenchForeignKey`=`f`.`id`
INNER JOIN `EnglishWords` e ON `e`.`id`=`m`.`EnglishForeignKey`
WHERE `f`.`Pronunciation` =  '[whatever]';
```

When I run it, what happens seems quite weird to me. I get the results of the query fine, 2 rows in about 0.002 seconds.

However, I also get a huge spike in CPU and `SHOW PROCESSLIST` shows two identical processes for that query with state 'Copying to tmp table on disk'. These seem to keep running endlessly until I kill them or the system freezes.

None of the tables involved is big - between 100k and 600k rows each. `tmp_table_size` and `max_heap_table_size` are both 16777216.

Edit: `EXPLAIN` on the statement gives:

+edit reduced keylen of Pronunciation to 112

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+----------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                               | key             | key_len | ref                        | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+----------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | f     | ref    | PRIMARY,Pronunciation                                       | Pronunciation   | 112     | const                      |    2 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | m     | ref    | tmpindex,CombinedIndex,FrenchForeignKey,EnglishForeignKey   | tmpindex        | 4       | dict.f.id                  |    1 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | e     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,id                                                  | PRIMARY         | 4       | dict.m.EnglishForeignKey   |    1 |                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+----------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

I'd be grateful if someone could point out what might be causing this. **What I really don't understand is what MySQL is doing - surely if the query is complete then it doesn't need to do anything else?**

## UPDATE

Thanks for all the responses. I learnt something from all of them. This query was made massively faster after following the advice of nrathaus. I added a PronunciationHash binary(16) column to FrenchWords that contains unhex( md5 ( Pronunciation ) ). That is indexed with a keylen of 16 (vs 600+ for the varchar index on Pronunciation), and queries are much faster now.

Comment: what are your indexes? Have you tried using explain on this statement?

Comment: Thanks. Indexes on FrenchWord, Pronunciation, EnglishWord, FrenchForeignKey, EnglishForeignKey. ids on FrenchWords and EnglishWords are primaries. Edited answer to include explain.

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, your use of a GROUP BY clause appears inappropriate.

Comment: I'm using `GROUP BY` because FrenchWord is not unique in that table, and in this instance I only want to see each FrenchWord once (other times they need separating based on other columns. Should I be handling this differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by the EXPLAIN, you key size is HUGE : 602, this requires MySQL to write down the data.

You need to reduce (greatly) the keylen, I believe recommended is below 128.

I suggest you create a column called MD5_FrenchWord which will contain the MD5 value of FrenchWord. Then use this column for the GROUP BY. This assumes that you are looking for similarities, when you group by rather than the actual value

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to reduce the keylen as far as possible but it hasn't alleviated the issue.

First I changed the collation on that column from utf8_unicode_ci to ascii_general_ci, as the column only contains ascii characters. That took the keylen down to 202.

Then I reduced it from VARCHAR 200 to VARCHAR 110 as the longest string it contains is 110. The keylen is now 112. The query still causes a long 'Copying to tmp table on disk' process.

Comment: varchar is discouraged from being used as a key, in general, text, char, etc are not good keys. Good keys are unique elements, such as numbers, GIDs, etc. Change the varchar to char(110) yes I know it is more data, will make they key more effective. BTW: Do you actually NEED the data to GROUP BY? or just to find where they are the same? if the "sameness" is needed, use MD5(FrenchWord) (or SHA(...)) as the KEY value, this will reduce the keylen while not losing the ability to GROUP BY

Comment: Thanks so much. This turned out to be an excellent solution. I'm now searching for md5 hashes in a binary(16) column, which is much, much faster. Learnt something very useful today!

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing `GROUP BY`. This clause is entirely pointless unless you also have a summary function such as `MAX(something)` or `COUNT(*)` in your `SELECT` clause.

Try removing `GROUP BY` and see if it helps.

It's not clear what you're trying to do with `GROUP BY`. But you might try `SELECT DISTINCT` if you're trying to dedup your result set.

Comment: Thanks. I've changed the query to use SELECT DISTINCT and not GROUP BY. I also took out the ORDER BY, but still getting the huge 'Copying to tmp table on disk' process.

Answer (score 1):

Looking further at this question, it seems like you might benefit from a couple of compound indexes.

First, can you make sure your table declarations have `NOT NULL` in as many columns as possible?

Second, you're retrieving Pronunciation, FrenchWord, and id from your Frenchwords table, so try this compound index on that table. Your query will then be able to get what it needs directly from the index, saving a bunch of disk io. Notice that Pronunciation is mentioned first in the compound index declaration because that's the value you're searching for. This allows MySQL to do a lookup on the index, and get the other information it needs directly from the index, without thrashing back to the table itself.

```
(Pronunciation, FrenchWord, id)
```

You're retrieving Englishword from Englishwords looking it up by id. So, the same reasoning can apply to this compound index.

```
(id, Englishword)
```

Finally, I can't tell what your ORDER BY is for, once you use `SELECT DISTINCT`. You might try getting rid of it. But it probably makes no difference.

Give this a try.  If your MySQL server is still thrashing after you make these changes, you have some kind of configuration problem.

Comment: Thanks again. This has been a real education! So is the general principle to create indexes on the columns that are frequently retrieved together and in the sequence that they are retrieved?